# How to GetSearchCenterUrl from UserProfileApplicationProxy

Tags: search, user-profile, my-site

I want to get `Mysite` host's configured search center URL for the user profile application (UPA), but the `UserProfileApplicationProxy` class is internal, as all the other UPA classes in the `Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration` namespace.

How to achive something like this:

```
SPServiceContext current = SPServiceContext.Current;
UserProfileApplicationProxy proxy = (UserProfileApplicationProxy)current.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(UserProfileApplicationProxy));
string searchCenterUrl = proxy.GetSearchCenterUrl(ServerApplication.CurrentUrlZone, current);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have used. I adapted it from the following blog post: http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/getting-the-my-site-host-url-from-code/

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Retreives the search centre URL as defined in the User Profile Service Application
    /// Adapted from http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/getting-the-my-site-host-url-from-code/
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="site">Site Collection</param>
    /// <returns>URL of Search Centre</returns>
    private string GetSearchCentreUrl(SPSite site)
    {
        if (site == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("site", "The Site Collection provided must not be null");
        }

        string searchCentreUrl = null;

        // hack to get the Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles assembly
        Assembly userProfilesAssembly = typeof(UserProfile).Assembly;
        // UserProfileApplication and UserProfileService are internal classes,
        // so you cannot get them directly from Visual Studio
        // like I do with the SPServiceCollection type
        Type userProfileApplicationType = userProfilesAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication");
        Type userProfileServiceType = userProfilesAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileService");
        Type spServiceCollectionType = typeof(SPServiceCollection);

        // first we call
        // SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<UserProfileService>()

        MethodInfo getValueMethod = spServiceCollectionType.GetMethod("GetValue",
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[0], null
                );
        if (getValueMethod != null)
        {
            // get the generic version of GetValue method
            MethodInfo methodInvokeGetValueGeneric = getValueMethod.MakeGenericMethod(userProfileServiceType);
            if (methodInvokeGetValueGeneric != null)
            {
                Object userProfileService = methodInvokeGetValueGeneric.Invoke(SPFarm.Local.Services, null);

                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo applicationsProperty = userProfileServiceType.GetProperty("Applications", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if ((applicationsProperty != null) && (userProfileService != null))
                {
                    // Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationCollection
                    Object userProfileApplicationCollection = applicationsProperty.GetValue(userProfileService, null);
                    if (userProfileApplicationCollection != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Object userProfileApplication in (IEnumerable)userProfileApplicationCollection)
                        {
                            // you could compare the id for the service application id
                            // it is useful if there are multiple user profile service application instances
                            // since it is not common I ignore the condition now and exit after the first item

                            //System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi_Id = userProfileApplicationType.GetProperty("Id", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                            //if (pi_Id != null)
                            //{
                            //    Guid id = (Guid)pi_Id.GetValue(userProfileApplication, null);                                    
                            //if (appId == id)
                            //{

                            Type[] parameterTypes = new Type[2] { typeof(SPUrlZone), typeof(SPServiceContext) };
                            MethodInfo getSearchCentreUrlMethod = userProfileApplicationType.GetMethod("GetSearchCenterUrl",
                                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, parameterTypes, null
                                );
                            if (getSearchCentreUrlMethod != null)
                            {
                                searchCentreUrl = getSearchCentreUrlMethod.Invoke(userProfileApplication, new object[] { site.Zone, SPServiceContext.GetContext(site) }) as string;
                            }

                            break;
                            //}

                            //}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return searchCentreUrl;
    }
```